# write list items based on count

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of items (lets says 30 strings); I'm trying to figure out how to write to a txt file 5 items, then new line, next 5 items, etc. Like this:

```
List<string> blah;
//List contains:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

I want to write to a txt file so it looks like this:

```
1   2   3   4   5
6   7   8   9   10
```

I can't seem to figure out a counter that will write this. I'm using StreamWriter if that matters.

EDIT: This is what I have currently but only writes blank lines.

```
for (var a = 0; a < ls.Count; a++)
        {
            foreach (string s in ls)
            {
                if (a == 0)
                {
                    sr.Write(s);
                }
                else if((a % 5) == 0)
                {
                    sr.Write(s);
                    sr.Write("\t");
                }

            }
        }
```

This is driving me nuts because I know it a simple counter I need to basically say "after you write 5 items, start new line."

Comment: iterate through list with a counter. if counter mod 5 = 0, write a newline.

Comment: Please post the code that you have that isn't working properly so we can tell you what mistake(s) you've made.

Comment: @marcmiller2007 if you found a response to your question, please mark it as the answer, and vote up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on JohnP's comment:

```
for(var i = 0; i < blah.Count; i++)
{
    if(i % 5 == 0)
        //do new line

    YourPrintFunction(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In pseudo code

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
        append to empty file (value)
    } else if ((i % 5) == 0) {
        append to new line (CR LF + value)
    } else {
        append to current line ("spaces or tab" + value)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBulder();

        for (int i = 0; i < blah.Count; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(blah[i].ToString());

            if (i % 5 == 0)
            {
                sb.AppendLine();
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append(" ");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

With LINQ:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int i = 0;

blah.ForEach(s => { if ((++i % 5) == 0) sb.AppendLine(s); else sb.Append(s + "\t"); });

File.WriteAllText("filename", sb.ToString());
```